# Extra header parameters for multipart uploads

Tags: javascript, multipart

When making form requests, before each part in the multipart data, I get a couple headers inserted like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9GAg9hUgKAtE1jsV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="Awesome-1920x1080.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

Is there a way for me to add additional headers to this before the actual file data? Is there a way for me to tack on another variable to `Content-Disposition`?

Essentially, I need to be able to tell my server how big each file in the multipart request is. Is this possible? I'm currently using the jQuery File Upload plugin, which internally uses  FormData to append data.